# Ajuda para diminuir query mysql e subtrair valores

Tags: mysql

Tenho a tabela orcamento com as colunas tipo_id, uid_id, valor e data e montei a seguinte query:

```
SELECT 

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=1, valor,0)) AS despesa_janeiro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=1, valor,0)) AS receita_janeiro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=1, valor,0)) AS investimento_janeiro,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=2, valor,0)) AS despesa_fevereiro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=2, valor,0)) AS receita_fevereiro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=2, valor,0)) AS investimento_fevereiro,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=3, valor,0)) AS despesa_marco,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=3, valor,0)) AS receita_marco,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=3, valor,0)) AS investimento_marco,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=4, valor,0)) AS despesa_abril,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=4, valor,0)) AS receita_abril,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=4, valor,0)) AS investimento_abril,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=5, valor,0)) AS despesa_maio,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=5, valor,0)) AS receita_maio,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=5, valor,0)) AS investimento_maio,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=6, valor,0)) AS despesa_junho,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=6, valor,0)) AS receita_junho,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=6, valor,0)) AS investimento_junho,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=7, valor,0)) AS despesa_julho,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=7, valor,0)) AS receita_julho,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=7, valor,0)) AS investimento_julho,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=8, valor,0)) AS despesa_agosto,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=8, valor,0)) AS receita_agosto,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=8, valor,0)) AS investimento_agosto,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=9, valor,0)) AS despesa_setembro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=9, valor,0)) AS receita_setembro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=9, valor,0)) AS investimento_setembro,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=10, valor,0)) AS despesa_outubro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=10 valor,0)) AS receita_outubro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=10, valor,0)) AS investimento_outubro,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=11, valor,0)) AS despesa_novembro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=11, valor,0)) AS receita_novembro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=11, valor,0)) AS investimento_novembro,

SUM(IF(tipo_id=1 AND MONTH(data)=12, valor,0)) AS despesa_dezembro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=2 AND MONTH(data)=12, valor,0)) AS receita_dezembro,
SUM(IF(tipo_id=3 AND MONTH(data)=12, valor,0)) AS investimento_dezembro

FROM orcamento
WHERE uid_id=1
AND YEAR(data)=2022
```

No caso gostaria de opiniões a respeito do desempenho da query e se teria uma maneira mais elegante de montar, já que são exibidas 3 colunas por mês (totalizando 36 colunas) e principalmente se teria uma forma de pegar os valores (de cada mes) `AS receita_mes e despesa_mes` e fazer uma subtração direto da query exibindo outra coluna `AS resultado_mes` (ou seria mais fácil fazer direto no sistema)

Segue a estrutura de exemplo para simulações:

```
CREATE TABLE orcamento (uid_id integer, tipo_id integer, valor decimal(10,2) , data date);

insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 600.00, '2021-01-01');
insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 100.00, '2021-01-01');
insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 200.00, '2021-01-01');

insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 600.00, '2022-01-01');
insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 100.00, '2022-01-01');
insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 200.00, '2022-01-01');

insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 2, 5100.00, '2022-01-01');
insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 2, 600.00, '2022-01-01');

insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 3, 1600.00, '2022-01-01');


insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 600.00, '2022-02-01');
insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 100.00, '2022-02-01');
insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 1, 200.00, '2022-02-01');

insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 2, 5100.00, '2022-02-01');
insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 2, 600.00, '2022-02-01');

insert into orcamento (uid_id, tipo_id, valor, data) values (1, 3, 1600.00, '2022-02-01');
```

Comment: Favor [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o esquema da tabela `orcamento` e se possível uma amostra de dados para teste, pois há como melhorar essa consulta.

Comment: Nada contra , uma forma simples , creio que MySql não tenha sintax para Pivot Unpivot.    https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Para o total algo assim SUM(IF(MONTH(data)=1, IF(tipo_id=2,-1,1)*valor,0)) AS total_janeiro

Comment: Se tem um sistema em outra linguagem, provavelmente é mais prático um select mais simples, acumulando numa matriz de tipo x mês ou equivalente do lado da aplicação. Se está usando só o mysql, provavelmente é um problema tratado no [dba.se], pode ser interessante dar uma pesquisada. Ainda, talvez esta pergunta seja uma duplicata (o assunto de pivot em MySQL já deve ter solução no site)

Comment: Coloquei uma estrutura de exemplo, no caso essa consulta é para utilização em APP de android feito com o Kodular

Comment: Removi a duplicação do select, só pra simplificar um pouco. Você pode [edit] e formatar do seu jeito obviamente. Inclusive, para o site, poderia até remover as colunas não relevantes para o problema (como a uid_id)

Comment: O select depende também da tabela , creio ser uma tabela pequena , para milhões de registros talvez seja preciso pensar outra solução , outro ponto é que o pivot é por mês , que não muda , se fosse por verbas , centro de custos etc o sql precisaria de manutanção a cada mudança.

Comment: Então a ideia é um controle de orçamento mensal / anual, a tabela em si pode até chegar a ter muitos registros, mas quando for individualizado por Pessoas e mês no select, acredito não ter problemas de desempenho.